# Adding Add-Ons to Blender 2.8 Manually

Tags: particles, add-on, rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation

### ***I want to fill a glass with water and smash it.***

1. Fracture ADD-On unavailable. Need Alternative or a way to add it in 2.8

I just started in 2.8 but looks like the fracture add-on is unavailable. Is there any way I can install it into 2.8?

- It's a python file is there any code tweaking that can solve this? I already tried to install add-on from file button but that's not working.
  Check out the attached screenshot
  [image]
- What are some alternatives with using it?
- Any helpful links to tutorials and other similar threads are much needed and appreciated.

Extra Info:
I'm new to blender with an optimal experience in 3D modeling and rendering.
I'm more interested in the dynamics and physics part of Blender 2.8.
The model is still crude and it's a beer MUG that explodes once it filled with strong beer. Well, that's the whole idea behind it. So a whole lotta fluid simulation and rigid body particle animation.

Comment: You have a lot of extra detail that doesn't help describe your problem, I recommend stripping down the content of the question to precisely what you wish to see answered.

Comment: Narrowed it down. BTW the first few lines of question tell you precisely what I wish to see answered.

Comment: You...actually haven't.  Is the plug-in not working?  Is something about it not acting the way you expect?  Tutorials (like https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=3&v=Goav3zoIu6I) are all over the place, and SE is not the place for them.  Do you have questions mixing the shatter with a physics sim?  Are you trying to shatter like glass instead of the default break like stone?  All of these are singular questions.

Comment: @Kirbinator just give me a couple hours. I'll edit the question. I saw your posts and now I know the format. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It is not going to be an easy task to make it work in 2.80 unless you are very experienced coder with lots of spare time. It's better for you to wait for its developers to do it. It would be logical to assume this will not happen until some time after 2.80 is released. You should use working previous versions for the part of the work you need done with the add-on. I believe that will be the best solution.

Comment: @MartinZ thanks mate.. Let's hope a solution comes up..

Comment: Due to 2.8's python API changes, addons need to be upgraded. Most addons haven't been upgraded to Blender 2.8 yet. And lots of devs are waiting for an official and stable 2.80 release before doing anything because for now it's unstable and there still might be another API change in the mean time. I guess the best thing to do is to create your assets, physic simulations and stuff in 2.79, then bake it and render in 2.8.

Comment: @L0Lock that's a good idea!